# SQL Server: Replace invalid XML characters from a VARCHAR(MAX) field

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a `VARCHAR(MAX)` field which is being interfaced to an external system in `XML` format. The following errors were thrown by the interface:

```
mywebsite.com-2015-0202.xml:413005: parser error : xmlParseCharRef: invalid xmlChar value 29
ne and Luke's family in Santa Fe. You know you have a standing invitation,&#x1D;
                                                                               ^
mywebsite.com-2015-0202.xml:455971: parser error : xmlParseCharRef: invalid xmlChar value 25
The apprentice nodded, because frankly, who hadn&#x19;t? That diseases like chol
                                                      ^
mywebsite.com.com-2015-0202.xml:456077: parser error : xmlParseCharRef: invalid xmlChar value 28
bon mot; a sentimental love of nature and animals; the proverbial British &#x1C;
                                                                               ^
mywebsite.com-2015-0202.xml:472073: parser error : xmlParseCharRef: invalid xmlChar value 20
"And&#x14;you want that?"
          ^
mywebsite.com-2015-0202.xml:492912: parser error : xmlParseCharRef: invalid xmlChar value 25
She couldn&#x19;t live like this anymore.
```

We found that the following list of characters are invalid:

```
&#x0;
&#x1;
&#x2;
&#x3;
&#x4;
&#x5;
&#x6;
&#x7;
&#x8;
&#x9;
&#xa;
&#xb;
&#xc;
&#xd;
&#xe;
&#xf;
&#x10;
&#x11;
&#x12;
&#x13;
&#x14;
&#x15;
&#x16;
&#x17;
&#x18;
&#x19;
&#x1a;
&#x1b;
&#x1c;
&#x1d;
&#x1e;
&#x1f;
&#x7f;
```

I am trying to clean this data, and I found a SQL function to clean these characters [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/wardpond/archive/2005/07/06/a-solution-for-stripping-invalid-xml-characters-from-varchar-text-data-structures.aspx). However, the function was taking `NVARCHAR(4000)` as input parameter, so I have changed the function to use `VARCHAR(MAX)` instead.

Could anyone please advise if changing the `NVARCHAR(4000)` to `VARCHAR(MAX)` would produce wrong results? Sorry, I wouldn't be able to test this interface locally so thought to seek opinion/advise.

Original Function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnStripLowAscii (@InputString nvarchar(4000))
RETURNS nvarchar(4000)
AS
BEGIN
IF @InputString IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
  DECLARE @Counter int, @TestString nvarchar(40)

  SET @TestString = '%[' + NCHAR(0) + NCHAR(1) + NCHAR(2) + NCHAR(3) + NCHAR(4) + NCHAR(5) + NCHAR(6) + NCHAR(7) + NCHAR(8) + NCHAR(11) + NCHAR(12) + NCHAR(14) + NCHAR(15) + NCHAR(16) + NCHAR(17) + NCHAR(18) + NCHAR(19) + NCHAR(20) + NCHAR(21) + NCHAR(22) + NCHAR(23) + NCHAR(24) + NCHAR(25) + NCHAR(26) + NCHAR(27) + NCHAR(28) + NCHAR(29) + NCHAR(30) + NCHAR(31) + ']%'

  SELECT @Counter = PATINDEX (@TestString, @InputString COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN)

  WHILE @Counter <> 0
  BEGIN
    SELECT @InputString = STUFF(@InputString, @Counter, 1, NCHAR(164))
    SELECT @Counter = PATINDEX (@TestString, @InputString COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN)
  END
END
RETURN(@InputString)
END
```

Modified Version:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].RemoveInvalidXMLCharacters (@InputString VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    IF @InputString IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
      DECLARE @Counter INT, @TestString NVARCHAR(40)

      SET @TestString = '%[' + NCHAR(0) + NCHAR(1) + NCHAR(2) + NCHAR(3) + NCHAR(4) + NCHAR(5) + NCHAR(6) + NCHAR(7) + NCHAR(8) + NCHAR(11) + NCHAR(12) + NCHAR(14) + NCHAR(15) + NCHAR(16) + NCHAR(17) + NCHAR(18) + NCHAR(19) + NCHAR(20) + NCHAR(21) + NCHAR(22) + NCHAR(23) + NCHAR(24) + NCHAR(25) + NCHAR(26) + NCHAR(27) + NCHAR(28) + NCHAR(29) + NCHAR(30) + NCHAR(31) + ']%'

      SELECT @Counter = PATINDEX (@TestString, @InputString COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN)

      WHILE @Counter <> 0
      BEGIN
        SELECT @InputString = STUFF(@InputString, @Counter, 1, ' ')
        SELECT @Counter = PATINDEX (@TestString, @InputString COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN)
      END
    END
    RETURN(@InputString)
END
```

Comment: It sounds like the problem is at the point where the string is being put into XML - if you're using a decent XML tool, it should be automatically performing required escapes (or wrapping the text in `<![CDATA[` `]]>` blocks). You shouldn't be having to re-implement this kind of functionality.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever unfortunately, one of those "problematic" XML tools is SQL itself; if you use "FOR XML" on a SQL query to convert NVARCHAR data into XML, SQL will happily include invalid XML characters as their "expected" escape sequences; SQL Server produces XML that SQL Server can't parse :\

Comment: I am facing this problem exactly... still don't found any solution. In my case, the problem is even worst because I can't now before hand wich columns may contain invalid chars. :(

Comment: @VictorEspina, found a solution which might help you, if this is still an open issue. Please read my answer below.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I found a workaround to this issue, might be interesting for you...

Comment: `&#x9;`, `&#xa;`, `&#xb;`, `&#xc;`, and `&#xd;` are not illegal XML characters. they are tabs  and newline characters and removing them could yeild unexpected (likely negative) results

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61271185/475876

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is safe to use `VARCHAR(MAX)` as my data column is a `VARCHAR(MAX)` field. Also, there will be an overhead of converting `VARCHAR(MAX)` to `NVARCHAR(MAX)` if I pass a `VARCHAR(MAX)` field to the SQL function which accepts the `NVARCHAR(MAX)` param.

Thank you very much @RhysJones, @Damien_The_Unbeliever for your comments.

Comment: VARCHAR(MAX) = VARCHAR(8000)

Answer (score 15):

There is a trick using the implicit conversion of `VARBINARY` to base64 and back:

Here your **list of evil**

```
DECLARE @evilChars VARCHAR(MAX)=
  CHAR(0x0)
+ CHAR(0x1)
+ CHAR(0x2)
+ CHAR(0x3)
+ CHAR(0x4)
+ CHAR(0x5)
+ CHAR(0x6)
+ CHAR(0x7)
+ CHAR(0x8)
+ CHAR(0x9)
+ CHAR(0xa)
+ CHAR(0xb)
+ CHAR(0xc)
+ CHAR(0xd)
+ CHAR(0xe)
+ CHAR(0xf)
+ CHAR(0x10)
+ CHAR(0x11)
+ CHAR(0x12)
+ CHAR(0x13)
+ CHAR(0x14)
+ CHAR(0x15)
+ CHAR(0x16)
+ CHAR(0x17)
+ CHAR(0x18)
+ CHAR(0x19)
+ CHAR(0x1a)
+ CHAR(0x1b)
+ CHAR(0x1c)
+ CHAR(0x1d)
+ CHAR(0x1e)
+ CHAR(0x1f)
+ CHAR(0x7f);
```

This works

```
DECLARE @XmlAsString NVARCHAR(MAX)=
(
    SELECT @evilChars FOR XML PATH('test')
);
SELECT @XmlAsString;
```

The result (some are "printed")

```
<test>&#x00;&#x01;&#x02;&#x03;&#x04;&#x05;&#x06;&#x07;&#x08;    
&#x0B;&#x0C;&#x0D;&#x0E;&#x0F;&#x10;&#x11;&#x12;&#x13;&#x14;&#x15;&#x16;&#x17;&#x18;&#x19;&#x1A;&#x1B;&#x1C;&#x1D;&#x1E;&#x1F;</test>
```

The following is forbidden

```
SELECT CAST(@XmlAsString AS XML)
```

But you can use the implicit conversion of VARBINARY to base64

```
DECLARE @base64 NVARCHAR(MAX)=
(
    SELECT CAST(@evilChars AS VARBINARY(MAX)) FOR XML PATH('test')
);
SELECT @base64;
```

The result

```
<test>AAECAwQFBgcICQoLDA0ODxAREhMUFRYXGBkaGxwdHh9/</test>
```

Now you've got your **real XML including the special characters**!

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(@base64 AS XML).value('/test[1]','varbinary(max)') AS VARCHAR(MAX)) FOR XML PATH('reconverted')
```

The result

```
<reconverted>&#x0;&#x1;&#x2;&#x3;&#x4;&#x5;&#x6;&#x7;&#x8;  
&#xB;&#xC;
&#xE;&#xF;&#x10;&#x11;&#x12;&#x13;&#x14;&#x15;&#x16;&#x17;&#x18;&#x19;&#x1A;&#x1B;&#x1C;&#x1D;&#x1E;&#x1F;</reconverted>
```

Comment: how can you now decode the xml <XML>&#x00;</XML> for example?

Comment: @DannyRancher, What would you expect? What are you trying to *decode* and what comes out, when you *decode* `&#00;`? The best format for binary content within XML is `base64`... With this answer I just wanted to show, that it is possible to create XML including these entities. If this is a good idea is depending on the needs...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `nvarchar(max)` instead of `varchar(max)` but otherwise the change is fine.

Comment: Does passing a `VARCHAR(MAX)` field to the SQL function which accepts the `NVARCHAR(MAX)` param wouldn't cause a performance (conversion overhead) issue?

Comment: Yes, there is an overhead in working with nvarchar. However, XML is a Unicode format so it should really be stored in nvarchar. If your data is varchar you can safely use varchar(max) for the function.