# Keep danish characters (Æ Ø Å) in Openquery to linked server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, linked-server

```
select * from openquery(DATABASENAME_LINKED, 'select id, pe_department_id, pe_username, pe_name, pe_hours, pe_startpage, pe_admin from person')
```

Special characters are lost in this query. Is it possible to ensure a certain encoding in the code or somewhere else?

Comment: which server is linked (another mssql, or oracle, db2, ...)? what are the column datatypes? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/acb718fd-0943-4e1c-95b0-067361157821/how-to-use-openquery-for-utf8-character?forum=transactsql

Comment: It is a MySql database, I think. The datatype is most likely varchar

Comment: it may be necessary to configure the settings "collation compatible" and "collation name", or to cast the varchars to nvarchar, see MSDN article in prev. comment. what is happening with the characters? substituted by question marks, or omitted, or Å > A?

Comment: Ø gets converted to "Ã¸", for example. I tried to cast pe_name to nvarchar(1000) as per your link (thanks), but got an error. How do I mess with the settings you mention?

Comment: What's the configuration for the linked server? What are you using as an adapter to MySQL? Part of the issue here is that MySQL uses UTF-8 whereas SQL Server's `nvarchar` is UTF-16. So, some translation work is necessary and ideally your linked server driver would be doing it for you.

Comment: I'm looking at the configuration right now in SSMS. Collation Name is not set, perhaps this is an option? Collation Compatible is False and Use Remote Collation is True. The Provider is Microsoft OLE Provider for ODBC Drivers

Comment: Setting the Use Remote Collation to False made no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repurposing the function `UTF8_TO_NVARCHAR` from [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28168055/convert-text-value-in-sql-server-from-utf8-to-iso-8859-1), it will be possible to do the conversion on the fly:

```
SELECT 
    id,
    pe_department_id,
    dbo.UTF8_TO_NVARCHAR(cast(pe_name AS varchar(MAX))) pe_name,
    pe_hours,
    pe_startpage,
    pe_admin
FROM OPENQUERY(
    DATABASE_LINKED,
    'select
        id,
        pe_department_id,
        pe_name,
        pe_hours,
        pe_startpage,
        pe_admin 
    from person'
)
```

The more intuitive approach of casting the column with MySQL's `CHARSET` directive right inside the pass-through query failed with no useful error description, so we did not pursue this further.

Comment: Sadly, I get "Query completed with errors" and no error description for ucs2, "Unknown character set" for utf16. Also: "Cannot get the column information from OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "DATABASE_LINKED".

Comment: and pe_name is absolutely spot on.

Comment: if you have access to the mysql database, you could try to run the inner query (with the cast) directly on mysql. if that succeeds, make a view out of it and try to select from there.

Comment: I found a link to a function that fixed the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28168055/convert-text-value-in-sql-server-from-utf8-to-iso-8859-1. So now the code looks like this:

Comment: SELECT 
    id
    , pe_department_id  
    , DATABASE.dbo.UTF8_TO_NVARCHAR (cast(pe_name AS     varchar(MAX))) 
    , pe_hours
    , pe_startpage
    , pe_admin 
    from openquery(DATABASE_LINKED,'select id, pe_department_id,     pe_name, pe_hours, pe_startpage, pe_admin from person')

Comment: You guided me in the right direction so please leave an answer so I can accept with a thank you :).

Comment: I just edited the final version into the answer, may it help others in the future.

Comment: Thank you dlatikay, I will make sure to to that from now on.