# How to retrieve wrong charset encoded strings?

Tags: php, sql-server, character-encoding, special-characters

In my PHP script, I made a connection with the MS SQL database server with the following code,

```
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>$database,"UID"=>$uid, "PWD"=>$pwd);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
```

Mistakenly I did forget to specify the `"CharacterSet"=>"UTF-8"` in the `$connectionInfo`. Due to this reason, some Spanish and other characters have been encoded wrong. For example, "álgebra" is stored as "Ã¡lgebra". Now that I have set the proper character set during the connection to the database, new data is stored correctly. **But how can I restore the original strings that had been encoded wrongly and stored already?**

Comment: *"But how can I restore the original strings that had been encoded wrongly and stored already?"* You can't, the data has already been lost. You would need to reinsert the original data or `UPDATE` the existing rows while referring to the original source.

Comment: Isn't there any algorithm that can restore the original strings?

Comment: No, there is no algorithm or magic which can restore the original strings.

Comment: Data loss from incorrect code pages is in many way identical to truncation, @SamiulAlam . Unless you have a copy of the *original* information somewhere then the data that has been lost would remain that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you haven't lost anything. Just convert the string/column to binary and then convert from binary to string with the proper encoding.

```
--2019
select cast(0xC3A16C6765627261 as varchar(100));

declare @t table(thechar varchar(100) collate Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC_UTF8)
insert into @t (thechar) values (0xC3A16C6765627261);

select *
from @t;
```

Comment: This collation gives this error: `Invalid collation 'Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC_UTF8'.`

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28168055/convert-text-value-in-sql-server-from-utf8-to-iso-8859-1 ... equivalent to Xabi's answer

Comment: @SamiulAlam That should be because UTF8 collations are supported from SQL Server 2019 onwards

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I use this tiny function to convert from UTF8 that may help you:

```
create function FromUtf8(@src varchar(8000)) returns varchar(8000) as
begin
    declare @c char, @i int
    select @i = patIndex('%[ÂÃ][€-¿]%', @src collate Latin1_General_BIN)
    while @i > 0
        select  @c = char(((ascii(substring(@src, @i, 1)) & 31) * 64)
                         + (ascii(substring(@src, @i + 1, 1)) & 63)),
                @src = stuff(@src, @i, 2, @c),
                @i = patIndex('%[ÂÃ][€-¿]%', @src collate Latin1_General_BIN)
    return @src
end
```